# How do I have a variable determine how many decimal points to display? c#

Tags: c#, numbers, format

I want to have the user say how many decimal points they want to display, I am trying to use format specifiers like `{0:F2}` but when I try something like

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} added to {1} is {2:F{3}}", Num1, Num2, Answer, DP);
```

it doesn't work, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `.ToString(string Format)`:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} added to {1} is {2}", Num1, Num2, Answer.ToString("F" + DP));
```

This will pass `"F" + DP` for the format provider. So, if `DP = 2`, then it would write the `Answer` as `Answer.ToString("F2")` (2 decimal places).